# Yearly new and repeated customers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to identify the number of new and repeated customers yearly.

[image: the sample list]

According to above table, I listed down the new and repeated customers but this process has been done by manually and I do have a lot of customers to identify in this way.

[image: new/repeated customer list]

May I know is there any formula, so I can identify the number of new/repeated customers yearly.

Comment: Seems like yoiu need a pivot table...

Comment: well that is the table from pivot table

Comment: Is year 2012 your starting reference point?

Comment: Actually, the reference point is the previous years of the current year. I don't have data before 2012 so, I just took the number of customers after 2012

Comment: @broiling, how does any one know that?! You've not explained that in your question. Please edit your question to explain this

Comment: You will have to start at some year (Say the year of establishment of the business) and all customers acquired in that starting year shall be always NEW customers to count by default or simply omitted from calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use VBA, you can get the solution at a click of a button. This proposed solution mostly uses formula with very little VBA support and it's a 2-Step solution.

Since you are using Pivot Table, get your data in more easier to view format by exchanging Rows & Columns in Pivot Table i.e. Let Years be rows and Customers be columns.

Save your workbook as xlsm (Macro Enabled Excel workbook)
In the sheet where your table exists press ALT + F11 to open VBA Editor. From Insert menu insert a module and paste the following code in it. Save the code and Workbook.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delimiter As String, ignore_empty As Boolean, ParamArray cell_ar() As Variant)
For Each cellrng In cell_ar
    For Each cell In cellrng
        If ignore_empty = False Then
            result = result & cell & delimiter
        Else
            If cell <> "" Then
                result = result & cell & delimiter
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
Next cellrng
TEXTJOIN = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(delimiter))
End Function
```

This is a TEXTJOIN Function. This is available in Office 365 subscription but not in other versions. The VBA code is inherited from the below article.

Source  https://www.get-digital-help.com/2016/06/07/textjoin-function/

[image]

You need to create a similar table to be populated with 1's being traslated to OLD & NEW as shown in above picture starting row#9 in this example.

Formula in Cell B9

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B5,B4,0)),"NEW","OLD"))
```

Formula in Cell B10

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B6),"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B6,B4:B5,0)),"NEW","OLD"))
```

Formula in Cell B11

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B7),"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B7,B4:B6,0)),"NEW","OLD"))
```

Now drag the three formula across the length of the table. Your 1's are not translated to OLD & NEW as relevant. This is Step1.

Create a table of Years below that and two columns OLD & NEW

Formula in B15

```
=CONCATENATE(COUNTIF(B9:I9,"OLD"),"(",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B9:I9="OLD",$B$3:$I$3,"")),")")
```

Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to create an array formula. Now you shall see the formula wrapped in curly braces and your intended results for the year in that cell as required.
Drag this formula down till desired number of years in question.

Similarly put the following array formula in C15

```
=CONCATENATE(COUNTIF(B9:I9,"NEW"),"(",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B9:I9="NEW",$B$3:$I$3,"")),")")
```

and drag it down.

This is a two step process. For more better version one can opt for full VBA code that can achieve this at a click of a button.

This solution shall work only in this workbook because of custom created TEXTJOIN function VBA code. However if you have Office 365 subscription then it should work seamlessly in Excel 2016.

Comment: Hi Pat, thank you so much for your help. I do not want to show the name of the customers, so i just want to show the number of new clients. Is there any VBA or DAX function for that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe conditional formatting would do the job here.  In the table below, the New customers are green, and the Repeat customers are blue.

[image]

To be a New customer, the cell must = 1 and all the cells to the left must be blank, and to be a Repeat customer, the cell must = 1 and *any* of the cells to the left must be 1.

So a simple AND() function can distinguish these.

To set formatting for the New customers, select C2:F10 and choose "Conditional Formatting..." from the Format menu.  Add a new rule and choose "Classic" as the style.  Choose "Use a Formula..." from the dropdown, choose a format style, and enter this formula in the box:

`=AND(SUM($B2:B2)=0,C2=1)`

For the Repeat customers, add another rule and use this formula:

`=AND(SUM($B2:B2)>0,C2=1)`

Note: the procedure for doing this may be different, depending on your version of Excel.  The key is to find the dialog that allows you to use a formula to set the formatting.

If you don't want conditional formatting, you could use similar formulas in another part of the sheet:

`=IF(AND(SUM($B2:B2)=0,C2=1),"New","")`

`=IF(AND(SUM($B2:B2)>0,C2=1),"Repeat","")`

Filling these to the right and down will identify the New and Repeat customers.

I hope this helps, and thanks for clearly explaining what you're trying to do. I remember your question from a while back, and adding the small table showing which customers are New and which are Return made it much more clear.

Comment: Thank you so much, your help much appreciated. This solution works well :)

Comment: however, (1) is just sample and it reflects the fees. So it would be quite difficult for me to adjust all of them to make 1

Comment: Are you saying the cells don't contain 1, but a number instead? If that's what you mean, change the `C2=1` to `C2>0`.

Comment: Yes the fees that we charged from our customers. How about for minus figures? c2<>0 ?

Comment: That should work.